# SQL query to extract part of column

Tags: sql

I have a query as below, that selects Description from table where description contains 'legal:'

At the moment it extracts everything in Description field. What I want to do is only extract 50 characters from 'legal:' keyword on.

```
SELECT Description
FROM Issues
WHERE
Description like '%legal:%'
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What database are you using? Do you want to output legal: as part of the 50 characters?

Answer (score 6):

MySQL

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Description, 'legal:', -1), 1, 50)
FROM Issues
WHERE Description LIKE '%legal:%'
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56522/2)

SQL Server

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Description, CHARINDEX('legal:', Description) + 6, CHARINDEX('legal:', Description) + 56)
FROM Issues
WHERE Description LIKE '%legal:%'
  AND CHARINDEX('legal:', Description) > 0
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b859/1)

Comment: How about if I have a column type XML?

Comment: @SiKni8 You should write a new question on it.

Comment: Done :) ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631837/how-to-extract-part-of-a-column-in-sql