# How to extract part of a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following column in my SQL table:

```
CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/picture/img') AS [Image]
```

Which produces this:

```
<img alt="Basil Abdeljaber" src="/uploadedImages/svr/physicians/images/Image - Abdelj.JPG?n=2086" />
```

Is there any way in SQL for me to extract the string between `src="` and `"`, so I am left with: `/uploadedImages/svr/physicians/images/Image - Abdel.JPG?n=2086`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change your SQL to this:

```
CAST([content_html] AS XML).value('(root/Physicians/picture/img/@src)[1]','varchar(255)') AS [Image]
```

to query the src-attribute of the /root/Physicians/picture/img-node.

Comment: Thank you, but I get this error: `XQuery [query()]: Attribute may not appear outside of an element`

Comment: Try again please - I've updated my answer to use .value() instead of .query().

Comment: Thank you. I was looking into `value()` as well. That worked fine :) Thanks.

Comment: +1 a more elegant approach then mine :) XPath is not my strongest skill.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Image], CHARINDEX('src="', [Image]) + 4, (CHARINDEX('"', [Image], CHARINDEX('src="', [Image]) + 5)) - (CHARINDEX('src="', [Image]) + 4))
```

Here's how it works:  `SUBSTRING` takes three arguments:

- The original string,
- The index of the starting point from which to extract the substring, and
- The length of the substring

So in the code above, the first argument is your `[Image]` column.  The second argument uses `CHARINDEX` to get the index of the sub-phrase `src="` and then adds `4` to that in order to skip over that sub-phrase.  The third takes the index of the closing quote mark `"` minus the index of the `src="` that we already found, which gives you the length of your substring.

Comment: Thank you for the query and the explanation but I get this error: `Implicit conversion from data type xml to varchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.`

Comment: Then just replace all occurrences of `[Image]` in the code I gave you with `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [Image])`.

Comment: I replaced my existing line with this: `SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/picture/img')), CHARINDEX('src="', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/picture/img'))) + 4, (CHARINDEX('"', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/picture/img')), CHARINDEX('src="', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/picture/img'))) + 5)) - (CHARINDEX('src="', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/picture/img'))) + 4)),`

Comment: I am trying to use your query and replacing mine because it's not a table, just a query. When I execute my query, I am shown with the table and then it quickly disappears and I get this error: `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`

Comment: I dunno, but you might be able to debug it more easily if you break everything out into their own variables and query those as well to see what they contain.  For instance, declare a variable for your xml and assign `CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/picture/img'))` to it, then use that variable instead of hard-coding it into what I gave you.